# Satrt date and end date validation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7.1

I have start date and end date in string format.i want to compare end date and start date,end date should be greater than start date.How to do this.

```
NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];

_start_date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

_start_date = [df dateFromString: date];

NSLog(@"date: %@", _start_date);`
```

Getting nil on start_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert both the strings to `NSDate` objects using [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As your date is in `dd-MM-yy` format, do as shown below :

```
NSString *dateStr1 = @"21-3-14";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr1];
```

Similarly create another date, say `date2` Then you can compare these dates.

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");        

} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

Comment: in date my string value is in format:- "21-3-14".unable to get value.any help

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of NSDateFormatter.
Configure it.
Parse the strings to get NSDate objects (dateFromString:).
Compare them (compare:).